# List of coodinate systems with attributes

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a website which lists all common coordinate systems with their attributes (angle true, area true). I aware of [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/) but this do not give me the desired information(or I am too blind to find them).

A plus would be a searchable system with EPSG codes. Double plus would be a side in German (because  I am lazy)

Comment: What software do you use ? Because I asked that ESRI has their common coordinate systems on pdf that you can find on google.

Comment: you do mean [this pdf](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/gislab/HowTo/ESRI%20-%20Map%20Projections.pdf) ? I am using qgis, but my question aims for a more general purpose: entering an EPSG code and get the attributes as result

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ?  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/

Comment: What about this http://epsg.io/ ?

Comment: thanks for your effort but what I am looking for is something like:
- tipp in the EPSG code and get as a result not only where it is used but also the properties shape, area and direction. The first hint with the pdf was a good start :)

Comment: Are you looking for an extended version of https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/summary-and-guide-to-projections.html for example?

Comment: yes thats Excavatio what i am looking for! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As @PROBERT cites, if you are interested in discovering information about EPSG codes, one web such site is http://epsg.io, so if you want to find out about  EPSG::4326 you would use http://epsg.io/4326 and if you wanted to learn about EPSG::27700 you would use http://epsg.io/27700.

Additionally you may find the official EPSG registry (http://www.epsg-registry.org) useful.  You can search by code in the page, or if you know the urn you can retrieve WKT or GML directly such as with [EPSG::4326 as WKT](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) and  [EPSG::27700 as GML](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700)